# Operator Matching Error VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

So I am trying to work on programming a simple camera to use user input to move around the game world, when I came across some really weird operator matching errors (C2677 & C2678). 
They are from the lines

```
    camPosition += moveLeftRight * camRight; 
    camPosition += moveBackForward * camForward; 
    camTarget = camPosition + camTarget;
```

Definitions:

```
    float moveLeftRight = 0.0f; 
    float moveBackForward = 0.0f; 

    DirectX::XMVECTOR camPosition; 
    DirectX::XMVECTOR camTarget; 

    DirectX::XMVECTOR camForward = DirectX::XMVectorSet(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); 
    DirectX::XMVECTOR camRight = DirectX::XMVectorSet(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

And the errors read:

```
    Error C2677 binary '*': no global operator found which takes type 'DirectX::XMVECTOR' (or there is no acceptable conversion) 
    //Hovering "operand types are: float * DirectX::XMVECTOR" 

    Error C2678 binary '+': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'DirectX::XMVECTOR' (or there is no acceptable conversion) 
    //Hovering "operand types are: DirectX::XMVECTOR * DirectX::XMVECTOR"
```

It has compiled before. It compiled perfectly fine when I was using the namespace DirectX. I thought maybe something got messed up when I added some movement code. I removed the namespace and added DirectX:: to every definition and function. Error. The MSDN page for C2677 and C2678 did not help at all. Googlings only gave me with simple stuff.

Gyazo links:

https://gyazo.com/e2f62026d00e8fa82142b24de3fe32b5
https://gyazo.com/f1bbc321abc3a167d519bf1d671edcc6

Edit: I have no idea why or how, but it works now. So yay... There goes an hour of my time. >.> Damn it coding... lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would like to use this operator:

```
XMVECTOR    XM_CALLCONV     operator+ (FXMVECTOR V1, FXMVECTOR V2);
```

I think you have hidden it somehow like this:

```
namespace
{
    class Scalar {
    public:
        Scalar() {}
    };

    inline Scalar operator+ (Scalar s1, Scalar s2) { return Scalar(); }

    int f() {
        XMVECTOR a;
        a = a + a; // Here, you can't access XMVECTOR's operator,
                   // because name lookup stops with first operator found
    }
}
```